# How to use sed to delete every other line upto a given line number?

Tags: sed

I would like to remove every other line in a file starting from a given line number upto another given line number. My file has a header lines, footer lines and data lines inbetween. I want to manipulate only the data lines without touching the header AND footer lines. How do I do this?

Example foo.txt

```
header1
header2
header3
1
2
3
4
5
footer1
footer2
footer3
```

Using

```
sed '4~2d' -i foo.txt
```

deletes the appropriate data lines but also deletes lines from the footer

```
header1
header2
header3
2
4
footer1
footer3
```

What I want is

```
header1
header2
header3
2
4
footer1
footer2
footer3
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: In my actual file the words "header" "footer" etc do not appear. I am using them here to illustrate my problem. There are no easy identifiable words that appear in the actual header lines and footer lines that can be used. The only info I have is the starting and ending number of the lines

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Karl Nicoll, I am still trying to understand the complex structure of Stack Exchange. I thought I was posting to the generic stack overflow forum. Why is this question off topic to that. What kind of questions go on the generic stack overflow forum?

Comment: @Anu the question is fine here, although it could also posted in unix. I would say do it here, as more people is checking this site.

Comment: Hi @Anu! Please don't take it personally, "closing a question" is simply a hint that it might not be the best question for Stack Overflow for a variety of reasons :-). You've asked a good question, but since Sed is a Unix command line tool, in my opinion it would get better answers in the Unix Stack Exchange site, rather than here. Stackoverflow isn't a "generic forum" it's a Q&A site for questions directly related to computer programming. Check out the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '4,8!{p;b};n;p' file
```

or:

```
sed '4,8{N;s/.*\n//}' file
```

or:

```
sed '4,8{4~2d}' file
```

Comment: sed '4,8{4~2d}' file worked! I wanted to avoid actually writing out the pattern n;p; etc since my actual file has 100s of lines that need to be modified. While I like the awk scripts, they are not as elegant as the sed onliners :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of the lines, you can do:

```
$ awk -v header=3 -v footer=9 'NR<=header || NR%2 || NR>=footer' file
header1
header2
header3
2
4
footer1
footer2
footer3
```

As `NR` refers to the number of line, it is just a matter of playing with the numbers you provide. Or you can also hardcode them:

```
$ awk 'NR<=3 || NR%2 || NR>=9' file
```

---

You can maybe re-print the lines after a number. In this case, we print back from `10` to `12`:

```
$ sed -e '4~2d; 10,12p' file
header1
header2
header3
2
4
footer1
footer3
footer3
```

---

In case `awk` is admitted:

```
$ awk '/header/ || /footer/ || NR%2' file
header1
header2
header3
2
4
footer1
footer2
footer3
```

This evaluates as true (and hence prints the lines) if either of these accomplishes:

- line contains "header"
- line contains "footer"
- the number of line is `2k+1`.

Or shorter ([thanks Jotne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698061/how-to-use-sed-to-delete-every-other-line-upto-a-given-line-number/22698161#comment34584415_22698161)!)

```
awk '/header|footer/ || NR%2' file
```

Comment: Can be shorten some: `awk '/header|footer/ || NR%2'`

Comment: Thanks @Jotne ! Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: You need tho remove one `|`, so its only one `|` inside the regex, se my sample.

Comment: The sed command replaces line "footer2" with "footer3". My actual file is not as simple and the lines do not have the words "header, footer" etc in them.

Comment: @Anu so you are planning to use the line number for that instead of the text itself? Is so, what's the pattern on that? Because `awk` may be best as per the `NR`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with `awk` if you can't use regex for identifying headers and footers **and** assuming you have headers on first 3 and footers on last 3 lines (if not then modify the following code appropriately):

```
$ awk '{ 
    line[NR] = $0 
}
END {
    while(x<3) print line[++x]; 
    for(x=4; x<=(NR-3); x++)
        if(x%2) print line[x]
    x=NR-3
    while(x<NR) print line[++x]
}' file
```